Inequality involving floor of logartithm
I have tested numerically that
$$\lfloor \log_k(r)\rfloor\leq r/k^2+1,$$
for every $k,r\in\mathbb{N}$, $k\geq 2$. I tried using calculus, but since the inequality is not true if we remove the floor function, that didn't work. Induction also seems hopeless. Any other ideas?

It suffices to prove the inequality for $r=k^p$ with $p=0,1,2,
\cdots$, and for $p=0,1,2$ the result is trivial, hence we may assume $p\geq3$. So now what we need to show reduces to
$$p\leq k^{p-2}+1\quad\text{for $p\geq3$ and $k\geq2$},$$
or equivalently, by taking logarithm,
$$(p-2)\log k\geq\log(p-1)\quad\text{for $p\geq3$ and $k\geq2$}.$$
Elementary calculus shows that the function
$$f(x):=\frac{\log(x-1)}{x-2}$$
is decreasing when $x\geq3$, hence
$$\frac{\log(p-1)}{p-2}\leq f(3)=\log2\leq\log k\quad\text{for all $k\geq2$},$$
which gives the desired result.
